# Understanding DAG visualization. Why does my job take so long?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a spark job that takes far too long. There is a stage with 432 tasks. 395 tasks complete almost immediately. Over the next 10 hours the remaining tasks struggle to finish. I get about another 30 tasks completed before killing the cluster, tweaking the code and trying again. But I'm working in the dark, as I don't know what's causing the job to take so long.

I discovered the DAG visualization page. For this job, it looks like this:

[image: DAG visualization of job that takes too long]

The page also reports that stages 31,31,34,35 & 36 are done. 33 is pending and 37 is in progress.

**Question 1, as an aside**: How is stage 33 pending and stage 34 complete, when 34 is dependent on 33?

If I drill into stage 37, I see this DAG.

[image: DAG of long-running stage]

**Question 2**: Does this give me any clues as to why my stage is long-running? It doesn't seem to.

The summary of tasks that have completed so far (currently at the 1.1hr mark).

[image: Summary of tasks completed at 1.1hrs]

Zoomed in on the max values:

[image: Max metrics for tasks completed]

Edit: Here's what my executors are up to:

[image: Executor summary]

**Question 3**: Are any of these values of concern? They all seem reasonable to me.

And **Final question**: Where else can I be looking to understand what my executors are churning over?

Edit: I have found that the stack dump on the Executors page is helpful in understanding exactly where the bottleneck is. Are there any other clues I've missed in terms of optimising this job?

Comment: What kind of task are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: From a subset of edges in a graph, walk a subset of regions in a graph measuring distance and then merge all results to find the shortest path from every edge to any seed edge. Stage 37 is the recursive A* walk from a set of no more than 32 geographically proximate seed edges to a partition of the graph. The thread dumps show that a lot of time is spent in `Set.diff(Set)` operations as it recurses. So I've reworked that portion to be more efficient & trying again.

Comment: Job completed in 1.3 minutes!! Either I've just introduced a bug, or that's the easiest optimisation I'm likely to see in my life.

Comment: You might be able to do this... but maybe not. I had a similar problem with some tree generation. Spark isn't designed for iterative and dependent tasks (well usually, there is GraphX, but even it has limitations). The "transformations" form an AST that is executed on an "action" (like collect). But if you go in a while loop the AST just gets appended too. "Recursion" seems like it might be an issue.

Comment: Yes, I've learned not to do any recursive work with `RDD`s. Instead the work is apportioned for parallelisation and the recursion done within each work unit & results merged afterwards. i.e. rule of thumb: never have an RDD as parameter to a recursive method.